# How to get screen X and Y of an Excel 2003 cell in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2003

How can I find the absolute position of a cell in Excel 2003 (e.g. relative to the screen[s]) when writing a C# Excel 2003 Add-in.

The Top and Left properties of a Range (such as ActiveCell) seem to give the X and Y relative to the top-left hand cell. Window.Left and Top give the X and Y of the window, but I can't find a way to get the size of the bit in the middle (consisting of Toolbars and such).

The aim here is to display a WPF form that relates to the selected cell, and is positioned adjacent to it.

I feel like I'm missing something basic here. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. The closest you can get is `UsableHeight` and `UsableWidth` of the active window (`Application.Windows` collection), together with `Top` and `Left` of said window and `Width` and `Height` of the main Excel window. That way you can get the non client area to some degree. But there is no way I know of to know how much nonclient area is above your window (menu bars, window caption bar, etc.) and how much is below (status bar)

Comment: Thanks for your help, InBetween!

I hadn't looked into `UsableHeight` and `UsableWidth`, but it's a good suggestion. It may be possible to infer how much is status bar by detecting whether it is shown or not (assuming that the status bar is always a fixed height). A little 'hacky' but if its the best I can do...

Answer (score 0):

The following link has some VBA code, which might be able to point you in the right direction: [Form Positioner](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/formposition.htm) .

It's more involved than I would have thought, but if you need to find the height of some of the Excel commandbars, the following VBA code in their example might help:

```
'
' we'll assume that the application's caption bar and the formula
' bar are the same height as the menu bar.  If we can't figure that out, use 26 as a default.
'
If Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.Visible = True Then
    DefaultCmdBarHeight = Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.Height
Else
    DefaultCmdBarHeight = cDefaultCmdBarHeight
End If
'
' We have to have a compenstating factor for command bars. Load an array
' with the heights of visible command bars. The index into the array is
' the RowIndex of the command bar, so we won't "double dip" if two or more
' command bars occupy the same row.
'
For Each CmdBar In Application.CommandBars
    With CmdBar
        If (.Visible = True) And (.Position = msoBarTop) Or (.Position = msoBarMenuBar) Then
            If .RowIndex > 0 Then
                VCmdArr(.RowIndex) = .Height
            End If
        End If
        If (.Visible = True) And (.Position = msoBarLeft) Then
            If .RowIndex > 0 Then
                HCmdArr(.RowIndex) = .Width
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next CmdBar
```