# Excel addin: Cell absolute position

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, excel-addins

How can I find the absolute coordinates in pixels of a certain cell?

I am developing an Office 2010 addon (the Ribbon UI) and I add a new button to a new menu in the Ribbon and when the button is pressed, I want to get the screen position of that cell. The problem is that

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveCell . Top / Left
```

only give the position relative to the `A1` corner of the spreadsheet, while I want the position relative to 0,0 of the screen.

I found this: [How to get screen X and Y of an Excel 2003 cell in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283084/how-to-get-screen-x-and-y-of-an-excel-2003-cell-in-c-sharp) but it's for Office 2003 and I don't fully understand the answer.

I'm using C# for devel, but VB will also do.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the code you linked to won't help as it's for determining the height of XL 2003 and earlier toolbars at the top of the screen.

Comment: That's kinda what my point was and to not make a complete fool of myself that I have not looked everywhere.

Comment: @cdavid A bit late, but see if this works for you without problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29354020/904156

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21896#2), which contains the API calls used below.  I also was reminded that you can get the height of the ribbon with Application.Commandbars("Ribbon").Height.  So, in VBA you'd do:

EDIT: In response the Formula Bar and Headings height issue I added a function that hides them, gets the ActiveWindow.Height, then shows them and gets the new ActiveWindow.Height and figures the difference.  That function now gets called in the line below that adds together the heights before converting.  I think it works but I didn't do a lot of testing.

```
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88
Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

Sub CellTopLeftPixels(rng As Excel.Range)
Dim RibbonHeight As Long
Dim TotalTop As Long
Dim TotalLeft As Long

RibbonHeight = Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Height
TotalTop = (RibbonHeight + GetFormulaBarAndHeadingsHeight + rng.Top) * PixelsPerPointY
TotalLeft = rng.Left * PixelsPerPointX
Debug.Print "Top: "; TotalTop; " Left: "; TotalLeft
End Sub

Function GetFormulaBarAndHeadingsHeight()
Dim ActiveWindowHeightWhenHidden As Long
Dim ActiveWindowHeightWhenShown As Long

Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
ActiveWindowHeightWhenHidden = ActiveWindow.Height
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
ActiveWindowHeightWhenShown = ActiveWindow.Height
GetFormulaBarAndHeadingsHeight = ActiveWindowHeightWhenHidden - ActiveWindowHeightWhenShown
End Function

Function PixelsPerPointX() As Double
Dim hdc As Long
Dim PixPerInchX As Long

hdc = GetDC(0)
PixPerInchX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)
PixelsPerPointX = PixPerInchX / 72
ReleaseDC 0, hdc
End Function

Function PixelsPerPointY() As Double
Dim hdc As Long
Dim PixPerInchY As Long

hdc = GetDC(0)
PixPerInchY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY)
PixelsPerPointY = PixPerInchY / 72
ReleaseDC 0, hdc
End Function
```

The 72 above is the points per inch.

Call it like:

```
Sub test()
CellTopLeftPixels ActiveCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! @Doug The code is pretty ok, but it still has some issues, as far as I found out -- it is not taking into consideration the position of Excel on the screen, as well as the size of the formula bar and the size of the headings (A,B,C ... 1,2,3). For application, I found `appTop = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Top`, but I am still thinking on how to get the formula bar size and the headings size (if any). Help is very appreciated.

Comment: I've modified (hacked) the code to account for this.  Don't know if it's the best way.  See edits.

Comment: A very good idea with the formula bar. Unfortunately, the same thing won't work with the headings. And you can't make use of `UsableHeight` / `UsableWidth` either. I will mark your reply as the answer and try myself. If you are interested in more details, i've also posted the same question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/50dae716-598c-4b16-bd57-4e09b859c83e)

Comment: Whoops, I tested them both together and didn't realize the headings weren't working.  Thanks for the accept and good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I found this to work without any kind of hackery:

```
    Point GetScreenPositionFromCell(Excel.Range cell, Excel.Application excel)
    {
        var wnd = excel.ActiveWindow;
        if (wnd != null)
        {
            var result = new Point
            {
                X = wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsX((int)cell.Left),
                Y = wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsY((int)cell.Top)
            };

            //cleanup
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wnd);
            wnd = null;

            return result;
        }

        throw new Exception("Error retrieving active Excel-window.");
    }
```